# Split a string by "," and not spaces

Tags: java, string, split

Every time I try to split a string e.g. `foo,bar,foo bar,bar` it skips the string after the space.

How do I stop Java from doing this?

```
String[] transactionItem = transactionItems[i].split(",");
```

if `transactioItems[0] = Y685,Blue Tie,2,34.79,2`

it would output

```
transactionItem[0] = Y685
transactionItem[1] = Blue
transactionItem[3] = out of bounds
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.

Comment: And what are you saying the result is? You sure you're not confusing a printed output of an array with the value in each element? In other words, what does transactionItems[i] actually contain--"foo,bar,foo", or "foo,bar,foo bar,bar"?

Comment: I find this difficult to believe.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "it skips the string after the space"? My output is showing [foo, bar, foo bar, bar].

Comment: Given your text example, I still produce the correct array with a size of 5.

Comment: Try this code and show us the result : 

    System.out.println(transactionItems[i]);
        for (String str : transactionItems[i].split(",")) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }

Comment: So, have you fixed your problem ? Was one answed correct ?

Answer (score 8):

This code is working correctly:

```
String[] split = myString.split(",");
```

Basic demo : http://www.ideone.com/kLchx

With your new example, it works too : http://www.ideone.com/hWWzd
I think we need **more code** to search the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
transactionItem[3]
```

Should be 2 instead of 3. Arrays are 0 indexed.

Comment: But le fourth element ([3]) should be defined : 34.79

Comment: @brainzzy given his example his array size is 5. The 3rd index should exist and would return 34.79